# Is it possible to mount an Azure datalake as a drive on a linux server?

Tags: linux, azure, hadoop, azure-data-lake

Our end goal is for our Linux VM servers to access the Azure Datalake directly as a mounted filesystem.  Microsoft states that the Azure Datalake is hdfs compatible so we were wondering if it is possible to mount directly through something like Fuse or indirectly through a Hadoop system?

Anything available in Azure goes.

Desperately looking for examples from somebody who has done this.

Answer (score 2):

[goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) supports mounting azure datalake: https://github.com/kahing/goofys/blob/master/README-azure.md#azure-blob-storage

Answer (score 1):

Presently, it is not possible to mount an Azure Data Lake Store account as a drive on a linux server.

Please add a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.